# Taking images of 3D model using STLRead

Tags: matlab, render

I'm trying to take "images" of a 3D model. I am able to load an STL file through [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22409-stl-file-reader/content/STLRead/stlread.m) code. What I need to do is be able rotate the object, and take "images" of it as it rotates.

stlread outputs a face and vertex structure that is compatible with patch(), so I can display the object, but I'm not sure how to actually store that image into a matrix.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are after is the function [getframe](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getframe.html), which captures the content of an axes and store the data as a regular "image" matrix.

I made a simple GUI to illustrate the concept. Basically I took the code from the link you provided (`stldemo.m`) and added a few features to take snapshots. In this case I added the command `rotate3d on` to rotate the femur inside the axes and a pushbutton whose callback calls `getframe` and captures the content of the axes. Basically you rotate the femur//patch object as you wish and you press the button to get a snapshot. In the code I make a new figure pop up to convince you it works, but you can of course do whatever you want with the data.

Note that using `getframe` outputs a structure with a field called `cdata`...that's what you are after in order to get the content of the axis as a matrix.

So here is the code and a few snapshots to illustrate:

```
function SnapShotSTL(~)
%// Taken from the stldemo.m file.
%% 3D Model Demo
% This is short demo that loads and renders a 3D model of a human femur. It
% showcases some of MATLAB's advanced graphics features, including lighting and
% specular reflectance.

% Copyright 2011 The MathWorks, Inc.


%% Load STL mesh
% Stereolithography (STL) files are a common format for storing mesh data. STL
% meshes are simply a collection of triangular faces. This type of model is very
% suitable for use with MATLAB's PATCH graphics object.

% Import an STL mesh, returning a PATCH-compatible face-vertex structure
handles.fv = stlread('femur.stl');


%% Render
% The model is rendered with a PATCH graphics object. We also add some dynamic
% lighting, and adjust the material properties to change the specular
% highlighting.


%// Create figure, axes and a pushbutton.
hFigure = figure('Units','Pixels','Position',[200 200 500 600]);
hAxes1 = axes('Units','pixels','Position',[50 50 450 400]);
hSnapShot = uicontrol('Style','push','Position',[50 500 60 30],'String','SnapShot','Callback',@(s,e) GetSnapshot);

patch(handles.fv,'FaceColor',       [0.8 0.8 1.0], ...
         'EdgeColor',       'none',        ...
         'FaceLighting',    'gouraud',     ...
         'AmbientStrength', 0.15);

% Add a camera light, and tone down the specular highlighting
camlight('headlight');
material('dull');

% Fix the axes scaling, and set a nice view angle
axis('image');
view([-135 35]);

rotate3d on %// Enable to rotate the object in the axes

guidata(hFigure,handles);

    function GetSnapshot

        CurrentImage = getframe(gca);

        ImageData = CurrentImage.cdata; %// Access the data. I create a variable but that's not strictly necessary.

%// Here a new figure is created and the image displayed in it... you can store it and do as you like with it.
        figure;

        imshow(ImageData);

        guidata(hFigure,handles);

    end

end
```

So the GUI looks like this when opened:

[image]

Then after a rotation of the object/femur:

[image]

and finally after pressing the pushbutton, a snapshot is taken (i.e. `getframe` is executed) and the resulting image matrix displayed in a new figure:

[image]

Note that I used `imshow` to actually display the image but the data can be manipulated as well.

Moreover, you can also use the following calling syntax for `getframe` in case you want to retrieve the colormap associated with your data:

```
F = getframe;
[X,map] = frame2im(F);
```

In this case, `X` would be equivalent to G when using this code:

```
G = F.cdata;
```

Finally, you could set up a loop in which the actual patch object is rotated by itself and frames are taken automatically. That should not be too hard to implement :)

Hope that helps!

Comment: Awesome then! Glad to help :)