# Taking screeenshots from a 3d model

Tags: c++, matlab, image-processing, stl

I am building an application that executes two steps: 
1 - Imports a 3d colored image file (such as .3ds file) then automatically captures a screenshot then rotate the shape for a very small angle (1 degree for example) and capture another screenshot and so on until a complete revolution. I can do something similar using MATLAB and an .stl file [Taking images of 3D model using STLRead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28490547/taking-images-of-3d-model-using-stlread) but the problem that .stl file don't carry color information like 3ds files.
2 - The taken screenshots then will be sorted radially (uniformly sorted on a circular path) and a final image is produced.

I can use any other procedure than I have mentioned before for obtaining the same result. I am not constrained with .3ds file extension any 3d image file can be used and using c++ instead of MATLAB.
Any suggestions are appreciated.
Samuel Farid

Comment: Read all the point coordinates with color information to a Matrix, then display the content with scatter3. Then you can rotate the camera position from view angle and save the the view as a frame. Now you can use these set of frames to even create a movie.

Comment: How can this be achieved from .3ds file? Will the scatter3 give the same accuracy and view like that of 3ds max or not?

Comment: That I don't know as I never imported .3ds file. Just saw this (http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3642-cad2matdemo-m). Scatter3 only plots the points, you may need a way to plot surfaces as well. We may try if you can provide a simple .3ds file.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very broad and generic question.  It would require us to teach you how to load a .3ds file which is far from trivial, I wrote one years ago that loaded the basics in just over 1800 lines of code.  Then write code to display the models with coloring and furthermore code to capture the images, along with rotational math (the easy stuff).  As far as I know, the 3D software (3D Studio Max) used to be able to do this internally for you and render them out to numbered files.  Likely something to look into.  I believe this to be your best bet honestly.